# Make segue that moves the opposite direction from "push" but is no different?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push, segue

This is the code I'm currently using for my animation that "pushes" in the opposite direction of the default "push" function:

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];


    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation
                                                                forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
```

It is slightly different from the default push animation though. It fades to black before off the screen while a standard push fades to gray only slightly before it gets pushed off the screen.

I want to make it the same animation as the push one but in the opposite direction.

Comment: Did you have a question, or are you just showing something cool?

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: @HalR do you have a potential solution for this?

Comment: My comment was serious-- I really have no idea what you are asking, but it seems like a really cool effect.